# jasmine:ci rake task hangs with phantom errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I'm trying to setup jasmine on a rails project.  I've got it working to the point that if I run `rake jasmine` and then hit `localhost:8888` with the web browser, I see all 5 of the included example specs pass.  However, when I run `rake jasmine:ci`, the server hangs without returning and when I go to the supplied `localhost:[port]` with the browser, it shows 3 errors, all of which say `TypeError: window.callPhantom is not a function in http://localhost:40993/__runner_boot__/phantom_boot.js (line 7)`  Any idea what I need to do to get the `jasmine:ci` task to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

Switching server to `thin` seems to have fixed it.

Added `gem 'thin'` to Gemfine and in `spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml` I set...

```
rack_options:
  server: 'thin'
```

And now...

```
$ rake jasmine:ci
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:37157, CTRL+C to stop
Waiting for server on localhost:37157...
jasmine server started
.....
5 specs, 0 failures
Randomized with seed 12286 (rake jasmine:ci[true,12286])
```

Much better.